# Expanding graph

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, random-graphs

How can I define expander graph with irregular degrees?

Is it possible to define an expander graph with almost regular degrees (all degrees are $d$ or $d-1$.)?

For example, is there any construction algorithm for semiregular graphs?

Comment: Are you asking how you can randomly choose an expander graph with those properties?

Comment: Yes, I want to know that how can I construct an expander graph with irregular or even almost regular degrees?

Comment: The definition of an expander in this case is the same as in the regular one: You want to have spectral gap bounded from zero in the sequence . As for examples, I would check generalized polygons. There is a book "Spectra of graphs" dealing with spectral calculations.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Can you explain more? Is there any construction algorithm in this case?

Answer (score 1):

**Introduction:**

Expander graph is a **sparse** graph that has strong connectivity properties.

The *key idea* here is "**sparse**". In other words, the number edges is relatively small compared to the number of vertices (see  this [book](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/expander-families-and-cayley-graphs-9780199767113?cc=fr&lang=en&) or [here](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~nati/PAPERS/expander_survey.pdf)). However the most common definition of expanders is for $d$-regular graphs, that's maybe because one of the following two reasons:

1-Most of the constructed expander graphs are Cayley graphs -which are regular graphs-(some times from the Zig-Zag product).

2-To be able to use Cheeger inequalities (which is also for the d-regular graphs).

**Original definition:**

The original definition of expanders is stated in [Recent Progress In General Topology III](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9789462390232) (definition 9.2).

**Definition 9.2**

A finite graph $G$ is a *$(k, ε)$-expander* if each vertex of $G$ has valency at most $k$, and $h(G) \geq ε > 0$.

A sequence of finite graphs $\{G_i\}$ is called an expander sequence if $|G_i| \rightarrow \infty$
and there exists $k, ε$ such that each $G_i$ is a $(k, ε)$-expander.

**Conclusion:**

The maximum degree in this definition should be upper bounded. The graph maybe regular or irregular. The graph $G_j$ can be $d$-regular, while the graph $G_{j+1}$ can be $d'$-regular. However, the maximum degree of any graph $G_i$ is less than or equal than some constant $c$ for all $i\in \mathbb{N}^+$.